# The rope data structure

Tags: c++, string, data-structures, ropes

I was reading about the rope data structure.I am interested in building a text editor using C++ and Qt. My question is: Does built-in string manipulating functions in programming languages like C++ use the rope data structure? Or do I need to write my own code for implementing ropes so that I can perform string operations like concatenation and deletion more efficiently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::string` is not a rope, but SGI STL provides [`rope`](https://wayback.archive.org/web/20171229113346/http://www.sgi.com:80/tech/stl/Rope.html).

If you plan on implementing your own rope, I'd recommend [SGI's rope implementation overview](https://wayback.archive.org/web/20171219030153/http://www.sgi.com:80/tech/stl/ropeimpl.html) for some implementation details.

Comment: So if I code my own functions for implementing ropes, will it be faster than the traditional built-in string functions? Are there any drawbacks if ropes are used?

Comment: @I'llsudeepdino008: For the most part, `std::string` works the same as `std::vector`: amortized constant `push_back` and `pop_back`, and constant indexing, but linear for insertion/removal. Short answer: yes, implementing rope will be faster than using `std::string`.

Comment: It appears that the SGI documentation has been retired. This link can still be accessed through web archives at https://web.archive.org/web/20170629152140/http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Rope.html